Saving Composer Snapshot fails
trying to save a snapshot for my composer environment
currently version composer-2.3.5-airflow-2.5.3
getting this message:
Failed to save the snapshot.
Failed to save the snapshot due to the following error: Fetching service account name of Cloud SQL failed due to the following error: Failed to run shell command "['bash', '-c', 'gcloud sql instances describe ** --project ** --format json']", details: "b''"; stderr: "b'ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) There was no instance found at ** or you are not authorized to access it.\n'"
has anyone encountered this issue?
which permissions does it refer to ?
I would appreciate any direction to look at.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Expecting a new snapshot to be created on the composer bucket in the snapshots directory which is the default directory for snapshots
